# To hold a newborn upright too early (under 2 months) will harm his spine?

Tags: newborn

I started holding my baby upright from the first month, coz I was told holding a baby upright will help him to burp.

I hold him upright facing my chest and with one hand supporting hit butt and the other hand protecting his neck. And he seemed pretty liked this position.

However, recently I read something on the internet that says such position might harm his spine as the baby is too young and his bones are not strong enough to support his own weight, holding him like that may cause his spine illy-shaped.

I'm worried about this as I've been doing this for 2 months and every day I might keep him in that position for about 2 hours in total (every time after he is feed and need to burp). Google gives too many opinions and I cannot decide which is authoritative.

This is my first child, and I'm kinda scared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked a number of sites and this [link was clear and did not disagree with Mayo Clinic](http://www.wikihow.com/Hold-a-Baby)

So as long as you support his head and make sure he can breathe easily, I think you are fine. I am sure this is not the only way you hold him and from my own preference, I liked to move babies into different positions.

Now that I am arthritic, I can only hold a baby if he or she is placed into my arms while I sit. I recently had a mum refuse to let me hold her child, and though I certainly wanted to -- the parent was right to choose what made her most comfortable. Parents are in charge, regardless what friends and relatives might want or think.

I know you want the best for your child and that you are naturally afraid. Please use this site and others for info, but the Mayo Clinic gives excellent, vetted advice that you can depend on to be the best free medical information available. Your doctor's office is also a great source of information. Where I am from, a public health nurse visits all new mothers and will return if s/he thinks you need more support. You might have to call your community to see if such a service is available to you.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so so much for the clarification. Now I can sleep at night. I'll make good use of these sites.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, holding a newborn upright in the manner you described (with one hand supporting his bottom and one hand supporting his neck/head) is perfectly healthy.

See this BabyCenter video at the 2:10 mark: http://www.babycenter.com/2_how-to-hold-a-baby_10368219.bc . It shows the upright position you described. This video was reviewed by BabyCenter's Medical Advisory Board, which consists of doctors and experts.

I would recommend to stick to reading articles by reputable baby/medical websites that are written by experts (such as BabyCenter or Mayo Clinic). If you start reading random user posts, you will be overwhelmed with conflicting information, some which are wrong. (Yes, experts can disagree too, but at least you are getting professional advice).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Shame that I can only mark one as answer... snuggle hold is exactly what I am doing!  Feel so relieved :)

Comment: "If you start reading random user posts, you will be overwhelmed with conflicting information, some which are wrong. (Yes, experts can disagree too, but at least you are getting professional advice)." Best advice for any non-medically vetted website. Everyone here means well, or mostly -- but anyone can be wrong. If you like some specific advice -- go check it out for yourself. Never take medical advice from anyone who has not examined the patient in person.